# Calculate triangle area with the right decimals in React

Tags: reactjs, math

```
class Q2Root extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
       super(props)
       this.state = {
           length : [
               {key:1 ,  a: 0},
               {key:2 ,  b: 0},
               {key:3 ,  c: 0}
           ],

           area: 0
       }
   }

   handleArea = () => {
       const s = (this.state.a + this.state.b + this.state.c) / 2
       const formula = Math.sqrt(s * (s - this.state.a) * (s - this.state.b) * (s - this.state.c))
       this.setState({
           area: formula
       })
   }

   lengthChanged = (event) =>{
       this.setState({
           a: event.target.value,
           b: event.target.value,
           c: event.target.value,
   })
}


   render() {
       return (
           <Aux>
               <p>Introduce the length for a</p>
               <Q2GetArea changed={this.lengthChanged} />
               <p>Introduce the length for b</p>
               <Q2GetArea changed={this.lengthChanged}/>
               <p>Introduce the length for c</p>
               <Q2GetArea changed={this.lengthChanged}/>
               <h3>{this.state.area}</h3>
               <button onClick={this.handleArea}>Get area</button> 
           </Aux>

       )
   }
}
```

React result 146871.43055641386

```
const a = 5;
const b = 6;
const c = 7;

const s = (a+b+c)/2
const formula = Math.sqrt(s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c))


console.log(formula);
```

jsBin result 14.6969

I am trying to get the area of a triangle with 3 values of choice. For instance, the value of a=5, b=6, c=7 is giving me 146871.43055641386. While in jsBin.com the result is 14.6969.
Could you please tell me how to get the right decimals to React.
Thank you,

Comment: I think `event.target.value` is actually returning a string instead of an integer. Make sure you convert it to a number before storing it in the state by using `Number(event.target.value)`.

Comment: You are absolutely right the returned value was a string rather than a number. However, despite the fact that it was returning a string it was the correct value, minus the location of the decimal. So, I have replaced the type with a number `<input type='number' onChange={props.changed} />`  and `event.target.value` with `Number(event.target.value)` as suggested.  Amazingly the decimal is now in the correct location, however, the values inputted are not individual keys any more. Rather than a=5 ,b=6 , c=7 is calculating a=7,b=7,c=7

Comment: I was wondering is there a way to identify the values with the keys so it will recognize as individual values. Thank you

Comment: To fix that, check the answer given below by @babak-yaghoobi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have revisited the code after a short break and yes the main issue was that the values of a, b and c were indeed strings instead of integers, hence the error in the area value.
Reference article: https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-convert-string-to-number-javascript/

Updated code below:

```
import React from 'react'

import Area from './Area'
import classes from './App.module.css'

const doArea = (a, b, c) => {
    const s = (a + b + c) / 2; 
    return Math.sqrt(s * ((s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c)));
    //return Math.sqrt(s * ((s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c))).toFixed(2);
}



class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            sides: [
                { text: 'Introduce the length for side a', value: undefined, id: 0 },
                { text: 'Introduce the length for side b', value: undefined, id: 1 },
                { text: 'Introduce the length for side c', value: undefined, id: 2 }
            ],
            area: undefined
        }
    }


    onLengthChange = ({ id, value }) => {
        console.log(value)
        console.log(typeof value)
        const sides = this.state.sides;

        const _sides = sides.map(side => {
            if (side.id === id) {
                return {
                    ...side,
                    value: value,
                }
            } else {
                return side
            }
        });

        this.setState({ sides: _sides })
    }


    onCalculateArea = () => {
        console.log(typeof this.state.area)
        const sides = this.state.sides;


        const sideA = parseInt(sides[0].value) || 1,
            sideB = parseInt(sides[1].value) || 1,
            sideC = parseInt(sides[2].value) || 1;

        this.setState({ area: doArea(sideA, sideB, sideC) });
    }


    render() {
        const props = this.state;

        const inputList = props.sides.map((side, index) => {
            return <Area
                inputText={side.text}
                key={`Input-` + index}
                inputId={side.id}
                onInputChange={
                    (event) =>
                        this.onLengthChange({
                            id: side.id,
                            value: event.target.value
                        })}
            />
        })

        return (

            <div className={classes.background}>
                ...
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

because you are using wrong way to setting a, b, c

your `React result 146871.43055641386` is because of setting `a=7, b=7 , c=7` !

you need just change

```
<Q2GetArea changed={this.lengthChanged} />
```

to

```
<p>Introduce the length for a</p>
<Q2GetArea changed={e => self.setState({ a: e.target.value })} />

<p>Introduce the length for b</p>
<Q2GetArea changed={e => self.setState({ b: e.target.value })} />

<p>Introduce the length for c</p>
<Q2GetArea changed={e => self.setState({ c: e.target.value })} />
```

I changed your in your code Q2GetArea = input tag and rewrite your class to :

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      a: 5,
      b: 6,
      c: 7,

      area: 0
    };
  }

  handleArea = () => {
    const s = (this.state.a + this.state.b + this.state.c) / 2;
    const formula = Math.sqrt(
      s * (s - this.state.a) * (s - this.state.b) * (s - this.state.c)
    );
    this.setState({
      area: formula
    });
  };

  render() {
    const self = this;
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Introduce the length for a</p>
        <input
          type="number"
          onChange={e => self.setState({ a: e.target.value })}
          value={this.state.a}
        />
        <p>Introduce the length for b</p>
        <input
          type="number"
          onChange={e => self.setState({ b: e.target.value })}
          value={this.state.b}
        />
        <p>Introduce the length for c</p>
        <input
          type="number"
          onChange={e => self.setState({ c: e.target.value })}
          value={this.state.c}
        />
        <h3>{this.state.area}</h3>
        <button onClick={this.handleArea}>Get area</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer output : [HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/calculate-triangle-6o71r-6o71r)